# How to sum up data according to a dedicated content from String?

Tags: java

I have to sum up data from a string below.This String is what I get from an API.Tried to convert to OBJECT or JSON or List>. But I failed.

```
[{\"username\":\"8000\",\"Amount\":\"33\",\"gsName\":{\"aa\":\"bb\",\"dd\":\"cc\"}},
{\"username\":\"8000\",\"Amount\":\"21\",\"gsName\":{\"aa\":\"bb\",\"dd\":\"cc\"}}]
```

I want sum up num for amount.
the result can be"amount 54" or "54"
Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: Is your exemple a string input or data representation ? (stored in an object yet ?)

Comment: It's not an object. It's a string. It is what I get from API, so I need to sum up amount from the data given.

Comment: looks like a `JSON`

Comment: Yes, it's like a JSON, but I can't use this one as JSON. I tried to convert into LIST<Map<String,String>>, but it has two } like }}, so it can't be converted correctly.

Comment: It's not a well formed JSON. Check the gsName object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) read in the JSON into a data structure and use a lambda to sum it up:

```
public class Data {
    private String username;
    private int Amount;
    private GsName gsName;

    // getters and setters
}

public class GsName {
    private String aa;
    private String dd;

    // getters and setters
}

String jsonString =
        "[{\"username\":\"8000\",\"Amount\":\"33\",\"gsName\":{\"aa\":\"bb\",\"dd\":\"cc\"}}, {\"username\":\"8000\",\"Amount\":\"21\",\"gsName\":{\"aa\":\"bb\",\"dd\":\"cc\"}}]";
Data[] data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Data[].class);
int sum = Stream.of(data).mapToInt(d -> d.getAmount()).sum();
```

Comment: Thank you. Georg. but I don't get the solution. because it has double }}.

Comment: Actually it does not have double }}, but it has a invalid JSON value: `gsName":{"aaa","pp":"cc"}` there is missing either a key or value for the entry **aaa**.

Comment: Well, it is. I already modified the invalid value. Now it is correct. Either ways, I have to sum up the data from the string given.

Comment: Updated my code, so that the JSON can be parsed correctly and given the sum of the data.

Comment: Thank you Georg. int sum = Stream.of(data).mapToInt(d -> d.getAmount()).sum(); Myeclipse shows error at position getAmount();

Comment: You have to create the getters / setters in the Data class. Name the getter for Amount `getAmount()` and you will have it.